# why does my code show this error when using Pyshark library

Tags: python, wireshark, pyshark

while am trying to use pyshark for some ctf tasks i got this output:

> traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "test.py", line 5, in 
>     if ("TCP" or "TLSv1.2") and ((packet.ip.src=="172.217.18.227" or  packet.ip.src=="192.168.1.100")) in packet:
>     File "/home/shanx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyshark/packet/packet.py", line 119, in **getattr**
>       raise AttributeError("No attribute named %s" % item)
>   AttributeError: No attribute named ip

here's my python code :

```
import pyshark
capture = pyshark.FileCapture("/home/shanx/Desktop/TASKS1.1/advancedNetwork")
val=""
for packet in capture:
    if ("TCP" or "TLSv1.2") and ((packet.ip.src=="172.217.18.227" or packet.ip.src=="192.168.1.100")) in packet:
        val= val+packet.sll.unused
val.replace(":","")
print(val)
```

note: it worked just fine without this instruction:

```
((packet.ip.src=="172.217.18.227" or packet.ip.src=="192.168.1.100"))
```

question: is there any fair documentation or tutorials for these kind of libraries ?

thank you so much for answering!

Comment: What versions of Python and PyShark are you using?

Comment: Did you try the different ways of accessing the `ip` shown in the [docs](https://kiminewt.github.io/pyshark/)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Both previous comments are good points (i.e. please respond to them)

Comment: Peter Wood : am using Python 3.7.5 and pyshark (0.4.2.9)

Comment: Alexander Cécile : I found a way using the "_all_fields" method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way while searching deeply in the docs, so for example if I need to know all the fields that can be provided by Pyshark for the **ICMP** packets , you have to type :

```
 val=pkt.icmp._all_fields
        print(val)
```

You will get this output:

```
$python3 test.py 
{'icmp.type': '0', 'icmp.code': '0', 'icmp.checksum': '0x0000fe60', 'icmp.checksum.status': '1', 'icmp.ident': '0', 'icmp.seq': '0', 'icmp.seq_le': '0', 'data': '5545734442425141434141494141422f65553841', 'data.data': '55:45:73:44:42:42:51:41:43:41:41:49:41:41:42:2f:65:55:38:41', 'data.text': 'UEsDBBQACAAIAAB/eU8A', 'data.len': '20'}
```

which is actually a dictionary that holds all the fields that you can access with python instructions !

Now you know what you can access and how !

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I also encountered on windows machines, but not linux machines.

I managed to bypass the problem by iterating through the whole capture file and appending every packet to an empty list:

```
packet_list = []
for packet in capture:
    packet_list.append(packet)
```

After this I could access attributes like ip.src from `packet_list`:

```
for packet in packet_list:
    if ("TCP" or "TLSv1.2") and ((packet.ip.src=="172.217.18.227" or packet.ip.src=="192.168.1.100")) in packet:
        val= val+packet.sll.unused
```

I am also new with pyshark so I don't know why does it work like this on windows, but it helped me.

Comment: thank you so much for your help but I think with large input of capture It will take double the time needed for processing my instruction so I found a way !